# My classes think that "self" is an argument that needs a value assigned

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm not sure why this is happening. It seems to think that "self" requires an argument, which doesn't make any sense.

Here's my code:

```
class Animal:

    def __init__(self):
        self.quality = 1


class Bear(Animal):

    def __init__(self):
        Animal.__init__(self)

    def getImage(self):
        return "bear.ppm"

class Fish(Animal):

    def __init__(self):
        Animal.__init__(self)

    def getImage(self):
        return "fish.ppm"
```

And the error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    Bear.getImage()

TypeError: getImage() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to instantiate `Bear` before you call `getImage()`:

```
b = Bear()
b.getImage()
```

`getImage` is an instance method, so it is only designed to be called on a specific *instance* of the `Bear` class. The state of that instance is what is passed as the `self` variable to `getImage`. Calling `b.getImage()` is equivalent to this:

```
b = Bear()
Bear.getImage(b)
```

So, without an instance of `Bear`, there is nothing that can be used for the `self` argument, which is why you see that exception when you called `Bear.getImage()`. See the [documentation on Python instance methods](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects) for more information.

If you want to be able to call `getImage` on the class `Bear` rather than on a specific instance, you need to make it a static method, using the `@staticmethod` decorator:

```
class Bear(Animal):

    def __init__(self):
        Animal.__init__(self)

    @staticmethod
    def getImage():
        return "bear.ppm"
```

Then you could call `Bear.getImage()`.

Answer (score 0):

getImage() is an instance method, so it can only be called with a instantiation of Bear class. So here is how you can do it:

```
Bear().getImage()
```

or

```
be = Bear()
be.getImage()
```